# How to correctly treat authors with compound surnames and imported automatically from Mendeley?

Tags: abnt, author

I am using `abntex2` and I know that in order to insert an author with a compound surname and all the letters of the surname are upper case, it is necessary that the author be described as:

```
Author = {Silva {} Júnior, José},
```

or

```
Author = {Silva, Júnior, José},
```

But I use Mendeley to manage my bibliographic references and it exports the .bib file with the author described as:

```
Author = {{Silva Júnior}, José},
```

Hence, `abntex2` does not correctly solve the reference writing in relation to the ABNT standard.

I've already researched and found nothing about it ... Does anyone know how it is possible to use the generation of references by Mendeley and LaTeX can capitalize all the letters of a compound surname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED:

I was able to solve...

For those looking for using Mendeley exporting the .bib file automatically and using abntex2 (which can save a lot of time and work) .... follow the tip to ensure a correct import of authors with compound surnames...

Step 1: In Mendeley go to Tools / Options / Biblatex and uncheck the option: "Escape LaTeX special characters (# {}% etc.)"

Step 2: In the author's reference, type so: Silva{\space}Júnior, José

Admittedly, from the point of view of the Mendeley authors' administration, it is not an elegant solution, nor is it correct. But since there is an incompatibility between a Mendeley export and the import of abntex2, with no solution from both parties and my problem was to a correction of the data, the cost of a {\space}, in the middle of the author's name, inside the Mendeley, was an admissible sacrifice in my case.

Thanks and Hugs to all,

Fabricio